# How to grep $ sign in script

Tags: shell, grep, dollar-sign

I am trying to grep for a line present in file:
`devnode "^sda[1-9]?$"`

The command that I am using is :
`grep 'devnode \"\^sda\[1-9\]\?\$\"' $file`

But it doesn't seems to work. I have made sure to use $ like "grep '\$'" as reported in some solutions but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me on this one, its frustrating.

Thanks

Comment: Is `$file` a variable containing the name of your file, a typo, or the actual mistake here?

Comment: Yes, it is variable containing the name of my file

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'devnode "^sda\[1-9\]?$"' file
```

Grep  understands  two different versions of regular expression syntax: "basic" and "extended."

grep 'foo' file / use Basic Regular Expressions

grep -E 'foo' file / use Extended regular expressions.

If use Basic Regular Expressions, ?, +, {, |, ( and ) have no special meaning.
If use Extended Regular Expressions, like this.

```
grep -E 'devnode "\^sda\[1-9\]\?\$"' file
```

Comment: If this works, the substantial change is to not backslash `?`; the other superfluous backslashes would merely have been redundant but harmless.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'devnode "^sda\[1-9]?\$"' $file
```

In POSIX BASIC REGEXP – https://www.mirbsd.org/man7/re_format – some chars only become special *with* the backslash, instead of without it.